# Showing two or more entries of the same column as one string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to display every person in my database and all movies this person has worked on, I would like to get rid of the double entries. Is there a way to make the entries look like

```
[Name] | [Movie title] | [Job1] "/" [job2?] "/" [job3?]
```

etc.?

[image]

Comment: Not rally easily.  This is best done at the application layer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hmm allright, this isn't going to the application layer sadly, I made it for an assisgnment on joins. the Joins work fine but I just don't like double entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select PersonName
      ,Title
     , Jobs  = Stuff((Select Distinct ' / ' +Job From @YourTable Where PersonName=A.PersonName and Title=A.Title For XML Path ('')),1,3,'') 
 From (
        Select Distinct 
               PersonName
              ,Title  
         From @YourTable
      ) A
```

**Returns**

```
PersonName      Title               Jobs
Arnie Hammer    The Loan Ranger     Actor
Dule Hill       Psych: The Movie    Actor / Producer
Jim Parsons     NULL                NULL
```

Comment: I actually meant the |   |   |'s to be a table with collumns but you technically answered my question correctly, nice job on the solution.

Comment: @TomLimpens Happy to help.  I trust you made the necessary adjustments?

Comment: I tested it out and it worked fine, but the goal of my assignment had nothing to do with this so I didn't go much further in to it. I just wondered if tehre was an easy way of doing it for presentation purpouses.

Comment: @TomLimpens See updated answer.  Is this more what you had in mind?

Comment: See how this is done in various databases: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat